# What is a URI Scheme?

Tags: protocol, internet, uri

I have searched for this question, but I haven't found a good answer.

Even the Wikipedia Article on [URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#Syntax) does not explain it thoroughly. I thought it was the protocol for accessing a web page. e.g. HTTP/HTTPS/FTP, but the wiki article says otherwise.

> Some URI schemes are not associated with any specific protocol (e.g.
>   "file") and many others do not use the name of a protocol as their
>   prefix (e.g. "news").

I know what *part* of the URL is the **scheme**. But my real question was **what does it do?**

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at the wikipedia articles (circa 2023), and it is still pretty sparse. I wish they would clear that up, because that part of the URL/URI namespace is used incorrectly, even in modern mobileOS architecture and by the GIT vendors.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Okay, I know what part of the URL is the scheme. But my real question was what does it do?

It simply tells you how to interpret the part of the URL *after* the colon.

For example, in `file://usr/share/doc`, the `file` tells me the part after the colon should be interpreted as a locally-available filesystem path. This isn't identical to a protocol, because there is no transport layer or encoding - a client just uses regular local system calls to access it.

Conversely, `https://programmers.stackexchange.com` specifies a scheme (`https`, which in turn [means](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.2) "HTTP over TLS"), but still requires the client to make its own choices about the physical transport used to reach it.

Comment: So `urn:isbn:096139210x` uses double scheme? This comes from the java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html .

Comment: ````https```` is not a protocol, it's a scheme that tell the client to use the ````TLS```` protocol and port ````443```` That's why schemes are not always associated with a protocol

Comment: @Liga - fair point, clarified.

Comment: @Niing - absolutely not. The URI scheme is "urn". _Everything_ after the first colon is interpreted according to the [URN scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8141#section-2) - you can see that "isbn" in your example is a **Namespace Identifier**.

Comment: So the scheme doesn't actually do anything? It's just a suggestion that the user or browser can choose to follow o not. For example, if I send an MQTT message to an htt p://somesite.com url, nothing is actually going to check that my message isn't http, and it's going to be sent as is.

Comment: It's a short character string prefix, of course it doesn't "do" anything. It's up to your MQTT client to validate the URIs you give it, if it makes sense to.

Comment: What's the point of URIs? What's the point of having a URI specification, when that specification is only: the URI will be `a:b`, and `b` is to be interpreted according to the specification identified by `a`.

Comment: What a weird question. What's the point of naming anything?

Answer (score 9):

The quote from Wikipedia may be a bit misleading. What it means is that for example the `file:` URI scheme does not state what kind of way is used to accessing the data (or whatever it is pointing to). With `http:` you know there is the HTTP protocol being used. With `file:` it's whatever the applications wants to use.

With `news:` the protocol name is NNTP, but the name doesn't reflect that. Which is a good thing in my mind, since `news:` is a lot clearer.

So the URI scheme is just the first part including the colon.

Answer (score 2):

The scheme indicates the addressing system used. URL's are really a unification of various disparate addressing systems. The part before the colon identifies the scheme in use, and everything after the colon is syntax specific for the scheme. Each scheme defines its own unique way of addressing resources. This makes the URL standard infinitely extensible through adding new schemes.

It is hard to say anything in general for schemes, because they are wildly different. In many cases the name of the scheme is the name of a protocol which can be used to fetch the resource (like http, https, ftp etc.) but that is not a hard rule, eg. the 'mailto' scheme indicates an e-mail address, but not a particular protocol. Some schemes don't correspond to any specific protocol, like the 'about' scheme used in web browsers, where the resource is not fetched via a protocol, but is built-in in the client.

Answer (score 1):

It's the part before the colon in a URI.

For example: the scheme for `http://en.wikipedia.org/` is `http`. The scheme for `file:///etc/passwd` is `file`. The scheme for `ftp://example.org/resource.txt` is `ftp`.

Comment: This is really the best answer for end users. When I am explain the web to new users and young kids, they understand immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I like Apple's description:

> A URL scheme is the part of a link that **specifies the type of application your device uses to open a URL**. Many apps support URL schemes: FaceTime uses URL schemes to make calls when a URL starting with `facetime://` is opened, just like Safari handles URLs starting with `http://`.
>
> Shortcut’s URL scheme, `shortcuts://`, launches the Shortcuts app from a link to perform a task such as importing or running a shortcut. These links can be useful in many different contexts such as on the web or when using Shortcuts with other apps that support opening URLs

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/shortcuts/about-url-schemes--apd621a1ad7a/ios)

Comment: I regret to observe that Apple has documented some, but not all of the URL schemes they use in their various OS variants. Also, some of the URL schemes they use do not seem to be registered with IANA. But they are not the only vendor that does this, GIT vendors seem to think that using git@<you-know-who.dns>: is a valid scheme. It pretty much isn't, according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2717

Answer (score 0):

The scheme is the first hierarchy of an URI and therefore the most 'prominent' part, which is used to identify the 'purpose' of the resource.
If you are interested in some 'kind' of resource (web links, news, files), you can tell by just using checking the scheme - not the whole resource string.

It's just a string repesenting a set of resources.